# Redirect with React 17

Tags: reactjs

Im upgrading from React 15.4 to React 17.0.2

```
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-router": "^5.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
```

I need to Redirect to a URL, but cant get it to work. This is how it used to work

In my record listing I hade a function

```
renderRedirect = () => {
    if (this.props.URL) {
        return <Redirect to={this.props.URL}/>;
    }
};

 render() {
    .
    .
    .
    return (
        <div>
            {this.renderRedirect()}
    .
    .
    .
    )}
```

My onClick or the DataTable record would then go to the parent component to see if the record is locked and if not would send back the URL to redirect too.

Only now that im upgrading im getting the error bellow.

`Uncaught Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Redirect> outside a <Router>`

How do I handel this type of redirect in the newer versions of `react-router` and `react-router-dom`?

Comment: Needing to use a <Redirect inside a router is not a newer version constraint. It's been like that for at least the last couple of years

Comment: okay. was not sure, but was working in my previous setup before upgrade. I might have soleved the issue though.
`import {Redirect} from 'react-router-dom'` and not from `import {Redirect} from 'react-router'` seems to have solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by changing:

```
import {Redirect} from "react-router";
```

to

```
import {Redirect} from "react-router-dom";
```

just add -dom.

Comment: You're a life saver!  I'm going through a particularly rough upgrade from v5 to v6 and this solved an issue I was running into.  Thank you!!